# What is mathematical notation to sort a set

Tags: notation

Let
$$
X= \{10,5,48,9,1\}
$$
We sort it,
$$
Y= sort(X)
$$
and
Y becomes
$$
Y= \{48,10,9,5,1\}
$$
What should be a mathematical notation for `Y= sort(X)`

Comment: We don't "sort sets" since sets are unordered.  $\{10,5,48,9,1\}$ is identically equal *as a set* to $\{48,10,9,5,1\}$.  We can however choose to write or refer to the set in a canonical ordering and we do so by using our words to say so.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I am not deleting the question; I hope it will be useful for someone else.

Comment: Sequences can be sorted. Sets can’t. But there is no canonical notation for a sorted sequence.